# node_modules in multiple directories outside any project folder

Tags: node.js, npm, path, node-modules, filepath

I've read a lot of articles on StackOverflow to understand node_modules,
non of them had the same 'problem' as i have. It's not a big problem since
node is still working fine and all. But the thing is, I don't like to have
unnecessary files or a bad file structure.

I am using macOS btw.

I understand that when you install the node modules globally they will go into this filepath:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules

but I also found another node_modules inside this path:

> ~/node_modules

Can i simply delete *this* node_modules? *edited*

> ^This is the main question I am asking, If i can delete the node_modules which is not inside usr/local/lib/.. nor inside any project folder.

Also I think I understood that even though you install the node_modules globally into the first path, stated in this post, I still have to install node_modules inside my project folder.

So what is the use of having node_modules installed globally?

Can I delete both paths and install node_modules only inside my project folders? Will this be more beneficial?

I also noticed when I was moving my project folders that contained node_modules into a different Disk. the file size of this folder increased with absurd numbers. Does that has anything to do with installing the node_modules globally?

*edit*

When I transferred my project files from Disk1 into Disk2, I was not able to move any project file back to Disk1 since the amount of file size of that folder increased that much. Im talking about moving 12 projects from Disk1 to Disk2, but each project folder became 2x bigger as those 12 project folders combined. Disk1 had 250GB of space. Disk2 had 1TB of space. Moving those project folders filled my Disk2 with 80% of space, I lost my mind when I saw this happen. Anyone has any explanation for this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Local npm package install will put a node_modules in that local location.  Global node package are usually packages you want to use globally across multiple project or they contain CLI commands (these are package that giving you command line interface).

You should manage your packages local to your project through the package.json file, and global packages through npm (use npm install, uninstall etc...).  When you move the project or commit it to git, ignore the node_modules folder (you can delete the local node_modules folder anytime) as it will get regenerate when running npm install using the information inside package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Managing packages locally is always good for your project although node_module being a large file of all dependencies can sometimes be not imported locally and works fine as it is been imported globally.Importing locally makes your project structure efficient and users can view the additional third party packages which you have imported. and as @noobius said you can ignore it while uploading your file to git as it will get regenerated when running npm install using the information inside package.json file.
Upvote if it helps